# Async await not working for function - create pdf document and then email it

Tags: async-await, pdf-generation, sendgrid

```
const pdf = require('pdfkit')
const QR = require('qrcode')
    
const emailTickets =  async (userEvent, tickets) => {   
    await createQRCodes(tickets)
    await createTicketPDF(tickets, userEvent)
    await sendGridEmail(emailDetails, true)
}
```

The problem seems to be that `async/await` isn't working properly for the `createTicketPDF` function.

When I run the above `emailTickets` function a blank pdf document is emailed. However, when I run it with the below `setTimeOut`, the pdf contains all the detail that I want.

```
const emailTickets =  async (userEvent, tickets) => {   
    await createQRCodes(tickets)
    await createTicketPDF(tickets, userEvent)
    setTimeout(async() => {await sendGridEmail(emailDetails, true)}, 5000);
}
```

I would prefer a solution where the code waited for the `createTicketPDF` function to finish before calling the `sendGridEmail` function.

Below is the code for the `createTicketPDF` function:

```
const createTicketPDF = async (tickets, userEvent) => {
    const doc = new pdf 
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./tickets/${tickets[0]._id}.pdf`))
    await tickets.map(async(ticket, index)=> {
        return(
            await doc.fontSize(30),
            await doc.text(userEvent.title),
            await doc.fontSize(10),
            await doc.moveDown(),
            await doc.text(`Venue: ${userEvent.venue}, ${userEvent.address1} `),
            await doc.moveDown(),
            await doc.fontSize(20),
            await doc.text(`Ticket ${index+1} of ${tickets.length}: ${ticket.ticketType}`), 
            await doc.image(`./qrCodes/${ticket._id}.png`, {
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'center'
            }),
            await doc.addPage()
        )
    })
    doc.end()   
}
```

I had a `forEach` loop in this function but replaced it with a map on learning that `forEach` loops don't work well with `async await`.

I have also tried using `(const ticket of tickets){}` but this didn't work either

VS code is suggesting that none of the `await`s within the map do anything

For completeness, below is the `createQRCodes`. This function is working perfectly.

```
const createQRCodes = async (tickets) => {
    let CreateQRCodes = tickets.map(ticket => {     
        return(
        QR.toFile(`./qrCodes/${ticket._id}.png`, String([ticket._id, ticket.randomNumber, ticket.creationTime.getTime(), ticket.userEvent]))
        )})
    await Promise.all(CreateQRCodes)
}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, [PDFKit](https://pdfkit.org/) is a synchronous library. The only thing that is asynchronous is writing the PDF to disk. So your code should not need to `await` anything within the `createTicketPDF` function. You do need to listen for the stream to finish though, so you could return a promise that resolves when the stream is finished, like this:

```js
const createTicketPDF = (tickets, userEvent) => {
    const doc = new pdf 
    const stream = doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./tickets/${tickets[0]._id}.pdf`))
    tickets.map((ticket, index)=> {
        return(
            doc.fontSize(30),
            doc.text(userEvent.title),
            doc.fontSize(10),
            doc.moveDown(),
            doc.text(`Venue: ${userEvent.venue}, ${userEvent.address1} `),
            doc.moveDown(),
            doc.fontSize(20),
            doc.text(`Ticket ${index+1} of ${tickets.length}: ${ticket.ticketType}`), 
            doc.image(`./qrCodes/${ticket._id}.png`, {
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'center'
            }),
            doc.addPage()
        )
    })
    doc.end()
    const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      stream.on("finish", () => {
        resolve();
      })
    });
    return promise;
}
```

```js
const emailTickets =  async (userEvent, tickets) => {   
    await createQRCodes(tickets)
    await createTicketPDF(tickets, userEvent)
    await sendGridEmail(emailDetails, true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It appears that there is some delay in saving the file to the server. I can make the code work by setting a settimeout() but this is a bit hacky

Comment: Ah, you're right, the PDF generation is synchronous, but writing to disk is asynchronous. I've updated my answer with better code, try that instead!

Comment: Glad to hear it!